# Could someone explain to me what uint64_t is doing exactly?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to undertand how this code works, specifically the line `msk = ~(uint64_t) 0 << (uint64_t)(high - low + 1);`

I really only am curious what `uint64_t` is calling/doing. Not so much the bit operations

Thanks for any insight!

```cpp
uint64_t clearBits(unsigned low, unsigned high, uint64_t source){
    uint64_t msk;
    assert(high < 64 && (low <= high));
    msk = ~(uint64_t) 0 << (uint64_t)(high - low + 1);
    return source & msk;
}
```

Comment: The `(uint64_t)` is casting the value to an unsigned 64 bit integer. Equivalent to `static_cast<uint64_t>` in C++.

Comment: `uint64_t` doesn't call anything, it is just a 64bit unsigned integer. This code is a function named `clearBits()` that is manipulating bits in an integer and returning the result. But you say you don't care about the bit operations. So what are you really asking about?

Comment: The subtracted parameters are `unsigned int`, which may not be 64 bits in width.  The cast converts the difference to a 64-bit number.

Comment: In general watch out for C-style casts like `(uint64_t)`. Those suckers turn off the compiler's brain and it will allow the conversion no matter the cost. Unless you're careful, using one trades a compiler error for a runtime error.

Comment: I'm curious about what the code is doing... It isn't clearing a "range" of bits... if you pass 2 and 4 as low and high it won't clear bits 2, 3 and 4 leaving 0,1, 5-63

Comment: Break the line down into pieces and understand what each piece does separately. Then you can usually put the pieces together and figure out the whole thing.

Comment: BTW, the constants 0, 1, and 64 are **signed** integer constants.

Comment: Basically, for the ~ part, what you want to make sure of is that you don't end up working with 0x0000'0000'ffff'ffff but 0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff instead. Something similar for the high and low part.

Comment: The unnecessary 2nd `(uint64_t)` for the shift amount indicate the original code author was unclear on the  proper usage of `<<`.

Comment: Question what this code suppose to do? It doesn't do what function name and arguments implies and can be extremely simplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint64_t` is an integer type. `uint64_t msk;` declares a variable of that type and `(uint64_t) 0` casts `0` to that type since the literal `0` is an `int`. Similarly, `(uint64_t)(high - low + 1)` casts the result of a calculation to the type `uint64_t`. However, this second cast is unnecessary, as discussed in the comments since the type of the result of `<<` only depends on the type of the first operand and not the second.

Comment: You may want to explain why the other cast is used also.  Consider that the parameters supplied are not 64-bit integers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm actually not sure why the second cast is necessary. Does `<<` require both operands to have the same type?

Comment: The `high` and `low` parameters may not be 64-bits; many modern processors the default int bitwidth is 32.  Best to have all your variables the same bitwidth when manipulating bits.

Comment: The other cast is pointless, @ThomasMatthews.  For shift operators, the specific integer type of the right-hand operand has no effect on the result of the operation.  It potentially changes the result in this case if `high <= low`, but only by exchanging one operation with undefined behavior for another.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm not familiar with the relevant specifications or standard practice. In practical terms, the right hand operand of `<<` should be between 0 and 64 which can be stored in much fewer than 64 bits. I guess in theory it can be larger, but I don't see any reason that an `unsigned` type in the RHS must be cast other than for consistent types.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are correct. The C standard guarantees that the result of a shift is the same type as the promoted left-hand operand (which would be `uint64_t` in OPs code ). So the second cast is definitely not necessary, and should be removed.

Comment: "should be between 0 and 64" --> [0 ... 63]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I purposely left the openness of each endpoint ambiguous. And I'm adding my own 65 bit type ;-) but yah...that was a typo. Feel free to edit a small detail like that.